# extending angular global object in typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm using Angularjs and Typescript and I would like to extend the angular object with a custom function like this:

```
angular.executeAfterDigest(function(){...});
```

How do I go around and do this? I suspect I need to extend IAngularStatic somehow or can I use something like angular.prototype? (I'm not very experienced with extending javascript object to start with).

Maybe it's more proper to create an "angularHelperService" that get injected instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tell typescript about it by adding to the interface : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts#L9

```
declare module ng {
    interface IAngularStatic {
        executeAfterDigest:Function;
    }
}
```

## update

**I would prefer not to change the angular.d.ts as it's a third party component**

You wouldn't put this in `angular.d.ts`. You would put this in your `globals.d.ts` (or `vendor.d.ts`) to document how you are customizing the vendor libraries (here angular) you are using in *your* project.

Remember: Interfaces are *open ended*.

Comment: I would prefer not to change the angular.d.ts as it's a third party component. But it might not be able to do it in any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Updating for current state of things:

**basarat**'s answer didn't work for me and it broke IAngularStatic typing in my app, but adding this to my global.d.ts fixed the custom angular extending function problem:

```
declare namespace angular {
    interface IAngularStatic {
        copyData:Function;
    }
}
```

I derived the `declare module ng` to `declare namespace angular` change from Definitely Typed structure linked by **basarat**:
https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts#L9

Answer (score 0):

Since angular is a singleton instance, you can just do:

```
angular.executeAfterDigest = function(fn) {
    setTimeout(fn,0);
}
```

When you call it, it is not guaranteed to execute after a digest. You would have to make sure that it is only called when `$scope.$$phase` is `$digest` or `$apply`.  Basically, it will only work when you're in the angular world.

Comment: As I'm using Typescript I get a compilation error if I try to "declare" an undefined function like that.

Comment: sorry, I don't know typescript