# Extending TypeScript Global object in node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, global

I have a node.js app that attaches some config information to the `global` object:

```
global.myConfig = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
}
```

The TypeScript compiler doesn't like this because the `Global` type has no object named `myConfig`:

> TS2339: Property 'myConfig' does not exist on type 'Global'.

I don't want to do this:

```
global['myConfig'] = { ... }
```

How do I either extend the `Global` type to contain `myConfig` or just tell TypeScript to shut up and trust me? I'd prefer the first one.

I don't want to change the declarations inside `node.d.ts`. I saw this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280052/extending-angular-global-object-in-typescript) and tried this:

```
declare module NodeJS  {
    interface Global {
        myConfig: any
    }
}
```

as a way to extend the existing `Global` interface, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

> I saw this SO post and tried this:

You probably have something like `vendor.d.ts`:

```
// some import 
// AND/OR some export

declare module NodeJS  {
    interface Global {
        spotConfig: any
    }
}
```

Your file needs to be *clean* of any root level `import` or `exports`. That would turn the file into a *module* and disconnect it from the *global type declaration namespace*.

More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

Comment: I can't quite figure this out. I don't have a vendor.d.ts, so I made one, but it seems to have no effect. Should I be importing it?

Comment: `NodeJS` is declared as a namespace, not as a module

Comment: @basarat - RE: "Your file needs to be clean of any root level import or exports" would it not be possible to apply the "global modifying module" here as per https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-modifying-module-d-ts.html ? If I understand that example correctly, adding something along the lines of `declare global { namespace NodeJS { ... }}` should allow you to have both the global namespace augmentation and your module exports.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I don't have a `vendor.d.ts` file in my project. The typings are loading from `./node_modules/@types` in my case. How do I make it work?

Comment: How do I use interfaces from external modules as types? I want spotConfig of 'Sequelize.Sequelize' type. Now how do I do that?

Comment: @d512: Unfortunately, this won't work with ES2017 anymore. Sigh... (And as a note, I'm pretty sure I'm working on the exact same code base you were working on originally.)

Comment: Hi Basarat, your answer looks nice, but doesn't work for me, the only thing that works is what I have here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49021561/1223975

Comment: Basarat, can you help me figure out how to avoid declaring `global: CDTGlobal` in all my files?

Comment: This won't help for implicit global references, e.g. `spotConfig` instead of `global.spotConfig`. To fix this, add `declare const spotConfig: any`;.

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh Interesting, neither VS Code, nor WebStorm can autocomplete `spotConfig.` in TS files.
Only WebStorm can autocomplete `spotConfig.` in JS files.
And only WebStorm can autocomplete `global.spotConfig.` in TS files.

Did you make VS Code work with globals properties autocompletion ?

Comment: The link seem to be broken: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/project/modules

Comment: outdated - as of node 16 this should no longer be the accepted answer or it should get updated.

Comment: Also possible: `declare const global: NodeJS.Global & { spotConfig: any }`

Answer (score 140):

As of `node@16` the `NodeJS.Global` interface [has been removed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/53669) in favor of [`globalThis`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#type-checking-for-globalthis).

You can declare new global variable in a module file as:

```ts
declare global {
  var NEW_GLOBAL: string;
}
```

And in a non-module file (no top-level import/export) as:

```ts
declare var NEW_GLOBAL: string;
```

**Important note: variable must be declared as `var`. `let` and `const` variables don't show up on `globalThis`.**

Comment: This is the only answer that works as of Sep 2021! (Node v14 LTS)

Comment: That's a very good point regarding var in the context of TS declarations.

Comment: Saved my bacon. Thank you!

Comment: Not working for me, the compiler still complains with the following message: 'Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature'.

Comment: and how to use this NEW_GLOBAL which is declared and set in Server.ts in eg. UserController? Do I need to somehow import it? How Typescript knows that it was already declared in Servert.s?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it with Node18, I ended up using @ts-ignore, this stuff is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: To get `declare global { ... }` to work in a module file, with `"isolatedModules": true` in the `tsconfig.json`, I needed to add an empty export object `export {}` to the declaration file.

Comment: Thank you for this important note: variable must be declared as var. let and const variables don't show up on globalThis.
I suggest you highlight it even more by raising its font size and putting it at the top.

Comment: @Suisse you can refer to it as `global.NEW_GLOBAL` or `globalThis.NEW_GLOBAL`

Answer (score 83):

To avoid Typescript claim something like this:

> TS2339: Property 'myConfig' does not exist on type 'Global'.

I suggest to define custom types. I do it under `src/types/custom.d.ts` file in my project:

```
declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
        myConfig: {
          a: number;
          b: number;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I ensure these are considered by Typescript in `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  ...
  "files": [
    ...
    "src/types/custom.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Now you're safe to use your custom property:

```
console.log(global.myConfig.a);
```

Comment: This is the better answer. Just as extending `Window` client-side should use `declare global`.

Comment: This is better, tnx. is there any document about this syntax, `declare global`?

Comment: I get an error "A declare modifier cannot be used in already ambient context" .

Comment: `declare global` seems a invalid syntax

Answer (score 29):

Putting the following file into our project's root directory worked.

global.d.ts

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
  export interface Global {
    myConfig: any
  }
}
```

We're using `"@types/node": "^7.0.18"` and TypeScript `Version 2.3.4`. Our tsconfig.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6"  
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I am getting the error: `TS2339: Property 'myConfig' does not exist on type 'Global'.` with it.

Answer (score 15):

### Use 'namespace' instead of 'module' to declare custom TypeScript

If you use any of the above answers and are using a newer version of Typescript you'll get a nag about using **"module"**. You should consider namespace instead.

In order to satisfy the requirement here you'll actually need more than extending the Global interface. You'll also need to create a constant with the type as well if you want it to be accessible directly from the **"globalThis"** context.

**NOTE:** while the OP asked about an object literal the process is the same as you see here below. Rather than the **"Debug"** type being a function you would simply define the interface as need, then change **"debug:"** to myConfig or whatever you wish.

```
// typically I'll store the below in something like "typings.d.ts"
// this is because, at least typically, these overrides tend to
// be minimal in nature. You could break them up and Typescript
// will pick them up if you wish.

// Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested 
// in external modules or ambient module declarations.
export {}

declare global {
  // Definition or type for the function.
  type Debug = (label: string) => (message: any, ...args: any[]) => void

  // If defining an object you might do something like this
  // interface IConfig { a: number, b: number }

  // Extend the Global interface for the NodeJS namespace.
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      // Reference our above type, 
      // this allows global.debug to be used anywhere in our code.
      debug: Debug
    }
  }
  
  // This allows us to simply call debug('some_label')('some debug message')
  // from anywhere in our code.
  const debug: Debug
}
```

### How the above might be used

For completeness in this example all we did was define a global so we can log a simple debug message. Here's how we'd bind the method to our global context.

```
global.debug = (label: string) => (message: any, ...args: any[]) => console.log(message, ...args)
```

We can also call our global debug method directly:

```
debug('express')(`${req.method}: ${req.url}`)
```

Answer (score 9):

The only thing that works for me is this:

```
// lib/my.d.ts

import Global = NodeJS.Global;
export interface CDTGlobal extends Global {
  cdtProjectRoot: string
}
```

and then using it in other files like so

```
import {CDTGlobal} from "../lib/my.d.ts";
declare const global: CDTGlobal;

const cwd = global.cdtProjectRoot; // works
```

Comment: I am attempting something similar, but in regards to reading a configuration JSON file and then having it globally accessible by all my modules. I'm attempting to figure out a solution where I do not have to "re-read" the json file in each module but can't seem to pull it off.

Comment: then it is not Global as we have to import in all the files.

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me is:

```
declare global {
  module NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      myConfig: any;
    }
  }
}

global.myConfig = 'it works!';
```

Only downside is when using it you will have to turn off the ESLint rule `@typescript-eslint/no-namespace`.

For completeness here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2017"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "removeComments": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es6"
  },
  "exclude": ["dist", "node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work

```
declare global {
  var user: string;
  function greeting(user: string, message: string): string;
}
    
export {};
```

Make sure you are using the `var` keyword, and you are setting this up in a `d.ts` file. e.g `global.d.ts`.

**Don't forget to add the export statement**

You can now access this anywhere in your codebase. e.g `global.person`

Answer (score 0):

> Copy my answer of [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906359/create-a-global-variable-in-typescript):

[globalThis](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-4/#type-checking-for-globalthis) is the future.

```
// Way 1
var abc: number
globalThis.abc = 200 // no error

// Way2
declare var age: number
globalThis.age = 18 // no error
```

Comment: Looks good, but this gives error: ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined

Comment: This did work for me, to define a global `emit` function from a Ava test written in TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

I can get both type check and code intelligence.

```js
declare namespace NodeJS {
  interface Global {
    property: string
  }
}
```

But interface `Global` is point to `global.GLOBAL`.

You can get correct type check, is because:

```js
declare var global: NodeJS.Global & typeof globalThis;
```

But you can not get better code intelligence by useing `global.property`, unless use `global.GLOBAL.property`.

So, you need to define global var `global` and extend interface `Global` both:

```js
// myglobal.d.ts
declare namespace NodeJS {
  interface Global {
    property: string
  }
}
declare var global: NodeJS.Global & typeof globalThis
```

And now you can get `property` intelligence when you type `global.`