# Node.js global variable and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, typescript, module

I need to have some strongly-typed global variables.

As mentioned here: [Extending TypeScript Global object in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074713/extending-typescript-global-object-in-node-js), in order to add fields to the `global` variable I need to add a .d.ts file that extends the `Global` interface that's specified in node.d.ts.

Also, as Basarat mentioned:

> Your file needs to be clean of any root level import or exports. That
>   would turn the file into a module and disconnect it from the global
>   type declaration namespace.

Now, I need to have fields on the `Global` interface whose types are custom interfaces that I created:

```
declare namespace NodeJS{
    interface Global {
        foo: Foo
        bar: Bar
    }
}
```

I'm extremely not willing to use the `any` type.

I can move/copy all the interface declarations to this declaration file, but it's a bad solution for me, since both Foo and Bar in turn, aggregate many fields of other interfaces, including third party interfaces like Moment etc.

I need a solution for this paradox

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 13):

Here's an approach. I don't know if this is the 'correct' way of doing things, but it works for me with TypeScript 3.7.4.

1. Assuming your source files live in a folder `src`, create a new folder `src/types` and create a file `global.d.ts` in this folder.
2. Author your declarations using one of the following strategies:

   - If you need to import external types into your declaration file, use the following syntax:

```
import { Express } from 'express';

declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      __EXPRESS_APP__: Express;
    }
  }
}
```

- If your declaration file does not contain any imports, the above will not work, and you'll need to use this syntax instead:

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
  interface Global {
    __CONNECTION_COUNT__: number;
  }
}
```

4. Make sure your `global.d.ts` file (and any other files you might add to `src/types`) is picked up by the TypeScript compiler, by adding the following to your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "paths": {
    "*": ["node_modules/*", "src/types/*"]
  }
}
```

5. Use the global variable as normal inside your code.

```
// Below, `app` will have the correct typings
const app = global.__EXPRESS_APP__;
```

Answer (score 7):

I found this works.

Have one file that declares the property on the NodeJS.Global interface with the any type. This file has to be clean of imports or refrences.

**node.d.ts**

```
declare namespace NodeJS{
    interface Global {
        foo: any
    }
}
```

Then in the second file you declare a global variable that has the correct type.

**global.d.ts**

```
import IFoo from '../foo'

declare global {

  const foo:Ifoo

}
```

Comment: Note that when using this method all `global.foo` usages will still, annoyingly, be of `any` type. However, you will at least be able to use `foo` as `Ifoo` type globally. Good enough to move forward, however. I wish the TypeScript team would comment on best practices for this; it's been an issue for as long as TypeScript has existed.

Comment: i am getting this error TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/index.ts:3:8 - error TS2339: Property 'env' does not exist on type 'Global' while compiling

Comment: thiss really worked. The only solution I found that works. In my case, I only had primitive properties so in that case you only need node.d.ts global{ foo: string, bar: string } ...

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (node v16.13.2)

1. In your root create file `types/global.d.ts`

```js
declare global {
    var __root: string
}
export {}
```

Note that `__root` declared with `var` keyword. It works with `let` and `const` too, but in this case `__root` will have `any` type. I don't know why;) If someone can explain this it will be great.

2. Configure your `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "typeRoots": [
            "types"
        ],
    }
}
```

3. Use declared variable in your code

```js
// app.ts (entry point)
import path from 'path'
global.__root = path.join(__dirname)
```

```js
// anyFileInProject.ts
console.log(__root)  // will display root directory
```