# Extend a namespace from package typings

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I'm trying here to extend a namespace from package typings, `@typings/fullcalendar`.

```
/// <reference path="./types/fullcalendar" />

import * as fullcalendar from 'fullcalendar';
import { TimeGrid } from 'fullcalendar';

// TimeGrid and fullcalendar.views are used then
```

Originals typings can be seen [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/fullcalendar/index.d.ts).

And fullcalendar-custom.d.ts is

```
import * as FC from 'fullcalendar';

export as namespace FC;

declare class TimeGrid { prepareHits() }

declare let views: any;
```

This results in type errors, so it is obvious that `fullcalendar` namespace wasn't extended properly:

> TS2305: Module '".../node_modules/@types/fullcalendar/index"' has no exported member 'TimeGrid'.
>
> TS2339: Property 'views' does not exist on type 'typeof ".../node_modules/@types/
>   fullcalendar/index"'.

How should this be done the right way?

Can `reference` directive be avoided here, considering that `types` directory is specified in `typeRoots`?

The application is bundled with Webpack and awesome-typescript-loader, so the behaviour may differ from other compilation methods. At some point types seemed to be ok in IDE inspections (WebStorm) but still got type errors on compilation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We can import a namespace in a non-declaration `.ts`, and export it again as a extended type:

```
// custom-fc.ts : enhances declaration of FC namespace
import * as origFC from "fullcalendar";

declare namespace Complimentary {
    class TimeGrid {
        prepareHits(): void;
    }
    let views: any;
}

// apply additional types to origFc and export again
export const FC: (typeof Complimentary & typeof origFC) = origFC as any;
```

```
// use-fc.ts : consumer of extended declaration
import { FC } from "./custom-fc";

console.log(FC.TimeGrid);
console.log(FC.views);
```

(This somehow differs from your scenario, in that I'm using `@types/` packages and webpack `ts-loader`, but you should be able to do something similar.)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to avoid reexporting if possible since I didn't extend the package itself in the place where I extend typings, but it does the job. I ended up with `declare class Complimentary ... export default <typeof origFC & ExtendedFC><any>origFC; `. A namespace was ok for TS but caused some type issues for IDE.

Comment: Not working in TS3?
export default <typeof original & extended><any>original;
Cannot use namespace 'original' as a value.
Cannot use namespace 'extended' as a type.

Comment: Is there a way to extend original namespace without changing its name?

Answer (score 7):

You can easily extend the 'fullcalendar' or any other TypeScript namespace.

Example: create fullcalendar-extension.d.ts file

```
/// <reference path="<path-to-typings-dir>/fullcalendar/index.d.ts" />

declare module 'fullcalendar' {

  export interface TimeGrid {

    customField: string;

    customMethod(arg1: number, arg2: boolean): boolean;

    prepareHits();
  }

  namespace customNamespace {

    export interface AnotherTimeGrid {
      customField1: string;
      customField2: boolean;
    }
  }
}
```

> Note: ensure that this file is picked-up by the TypeScript compiler.

Use the newly defined types from the extended module.

```
// one way
import { TimeGrid } from 'fullcalendar';

const timeGrid: TimeGrid;

// second way
import * as fc from 'fullcalendar';

const timeGrid: fc.TimeGrid;
const anotherTimeGrid: fc.customNamespace.AnotherTimeGrid;
```

For more info on modules and namespaces you can check TypeScript documentation on [Modules](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) and [Namespaces](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) and using them [together](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html).

Cheers!

Comment: But how `customNamespace` is supposed to be recognized in 'one way'? I'm trying to do `import { TimeGrid } from 'fullcalendar'; class CustomGrid extends TimeGrid { ... }`, and TimeGrid and its methods aren't recognized from the interface (and I don't see the way how it's going to work in 'second way').

Comment: In the given example TimeGrid is defined as an interface, the class CustomGrid can only implement it. If TimeGrid is a class that can be extended in the fullcalendar lib, then declare it as a class in the fullcalendar-extension.d.ts file. It's easy as replacing the 'interface' keyword with 'class'.

Comment: About the imports, due to the limited object destructuring capabilities in ES6 modules, 'customNamespace' can only by used as shown in the 'second way'.

Answer (score 1):

Using latest TypeScript v4, when I had issues with combining external files and libs with **Svelte** I did this:

```
// root/my-declarations.d.ts

import { SomeNameSpace as SomeNameSpaceOriginal} from '../../any-relative-path/to/ts-file';
import {SvelteComponentDev} from 'svelte/internal';

declare namespace SomeNameSpaceExtended {
    function setValue(value:any):any
    let UI:SvelteComponentDev
    let abc:string
}

declare global {
    //this will add new items to top-level (root)
    //note: in my case, only importing "as SomeNameSpaceOriginal" gave me correct typing later using our new extended global SomeNameSpace
    let SomeNameSpace: typeof SomeNameSpaceOriginal & typeof SomeNameSpaceExtended;

    //this will add new items to window:
    interface Window {
        elementInside:'window.elementInside'
    }
}
```

Upvoted Answer in combination with https://stackoverflow.com/a/63973683 gives most understanding about how to extend things around.

Answer (score 0):

add `jsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.json` to your project
add any `.d.ts` file to your project

add code to declaration file

```js
import 'fullcalendar';

declare global {
    namespace FullCalendar {
        export * from 'fullcalendar';
    }
}
```

and then you can use this type under the namespace defined