# How use global variable in Jest and pass it through cmd

Tags: typescript, puppeteer, ts-jest

I'm trying to create some e2e tests via puppeteer and jest, and now I'm stuck with a problems regarding global variables. So I have 2 issues:

1. How can I use globals in jest with puppeteer? Now I have the following in my jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    globals: {
        URL: "https://demoqa.com/",
        value: "myvalue"
      },
    preset: 'jest-puppeteer',
    testMatch: ["**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[t]s"],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', 'dist'],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.ts?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    globalSetup: './jest.global-setup.ts',
    globalTeardown: './jest.global-teardown.ts',
    verbose: true
};
```

and then I'm trying to use globals in my src/tests/test.spec.ts like this:

```
console.log(URL.toString());
console.log(value.toString());
```

But this gives error that `value` is not defined, but `URL` has the right value as in the jest.config.js

What am I doing wrong?

2. How can I pass this globals via command line? I found in jest docs the --globals flag, and tried to use it like this:

`npm run jest -- --globals URL='someUrl', value='someValue'`

but it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use the `global` object (e.g `global.value`) to access globals in the tests

   ```
   console.log(global.value);
   ```
2. Use the `--globals` parameter to override globals in the valid `JSON` format

   ```
   npm run jest -- --globals='{"URL": "someUrl", "value": "someValue"}'
   ```

Comment: When I use it like `global.value` it says 'Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Global & typeof globalThis'.'

Comment: And it throws this when I'm trying to pass JSON string in globals `SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 1`

Comment: Adding `\` before `{` `}` and `"` helps but parameters from JSON are not passed to the code. Why?

Comment: Adding back slash

Comment: Its' a typescript issue. You have to define a custom type for the global. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074713/extending-typescript-global-object-in-node-js). Also, you can just use any for the global (global as any).

Comment: It means that you provided the invalid JSON. I've sent a valid and tested it before answering. You need to use quote '' for the JSON. And please, validate your JSON before passing it. https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: And you don't have to use the `toString()` method for the properties.

Comment: Thanks, the thing with defining a custom type works. But solution with passing json string not, I pass json from your comment and this error with unexpected token pops up. I always vlidate JSONs on the jsonlint.com

Comment: Happy to hear it.
Are you running it on Windows? Can you send the whole command with the `JSON` argument?

Comment: I'm running the following command in VS Code terminal in Windows:         `npm run test -- --globals='{"URL": "someUrl", "value": "someValue"}' ` and in my packaje.json I have the following script `"scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },`

Comment: I've finally figured out, but I dunno where I was whrong. So the following script works: ` 
 npm run test -- --globals='{\"URL\":\"https://demoqa.com/\",\"HEADLESS\":true,\"SLOWMO\":10}'  ` and also I have the same globals from this script in my jest.config.js. So now all globals are passing in my tests