# Namespace 'NodeJS' has no exported member 'Global'

Tags: node.js, typescript

I used to define global variables using the following code:

```js
interface CustomNodeJSGlobal extends NodeJS.Global {
  myGlobalVariable: unknown
}

export { CustomNodeJSGlobal }
```

In Node 14, but when I installed `@types/node` (which is currently in the version 16) it throws me an error `Namespace 'NodeJS' has no exported member 'Global'`. How can I declare global variables in Node 16 and above?

Comment: Did you configured node types in your `tsconfig.json` ?

Comment: You mean `types` field in `compilerOptions`?

Comment: Yes, when you declare `types` like `"types": [ "node", ... ]`

Comment: No, I haven't used that field, what should I put there?

Comment: The following answer may help you (but will not directly answer your question): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68262350/how-can-i-resolve-the-tsc-error-namespace-nodejs-has-no-exported-member-glob#answer-68262351

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extending TypeScript Global object in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074713/extending-typescript-global-object-in-node-js)

Comment: This would be the direct answer to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68328575/4554883

Comment: Thanks guys, it, I already checked your suggestions, and I found 2 more that are related to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56984941/12379333 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/69230938/12379333, but neither of them works for me without adding `// @ts-ignore`, bcs the compiler complains with the following error: 'Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature'.

Answer (score 5):

With Node.js >= 16, I think `NodeJS.Global` type is no longer available, but you can declare it like:

```
type NodeJSGlobal = typeof global;
```

Comment: where we need to declare this type