# How can I resolve the TypeScript Compiler error "Namespace 'NodeJS' has no exported member 'Global'"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, tsc

**QUESTION**: How can I resolve the Typescript Compiler (`tsc`) error "*Namespace 'NodeJS' has no exported member 'Global'*"?

While running `tsc`, I'm all of a sudden seeing the following error in a "legacy"(not new) project:

```
node_modules/expect/node_modules/@jest/types/build/Global.d.ts:85:62 - error TS2694: Namespace 'NodeJS' has no exported member 'Global'.

85 export interface Global extends GlobalAdditions, Omit<NodeJS.Global, keyof GlobalAdditions> {
                                                                ~~~~~~
```

I tried adding installing `@types/node` and adding `"types": ["node"]` to my `tsconfig` (as suggested in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68251777/namespace-nodejs-has-no-exported-member-global)), but that didn't help.

**Node version**: 12.18.4

**Jest version**: 26.5.3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to work around this issue by adding `"skipLibCheck": true` to my `tsconfig`.

TFM: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#skipLibCheck

Comment: I'm interested in other answers to this question, especially if they explain the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 7):

This is a known bug: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11640

Downgrading to `@types/node` v15.14.0 seems to work around the bug for me.

Comment: Upgrading `jest` to v27.1.0 fixed it for me.