# type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature

Tags: node.js, typescript, microservices

i get this error whenever i try to add a function to the global nodejs global namsepace in a TypeScript environment.

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis'
> has no index signature

declaring the global namespace

```
declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      signin(): string[]
    }
  }
}
```

so if i try this

```
global.signin = () => {}
```

it returns a

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis'
> has no index signature

Comment: I was hoping for a proper answer to this exact question. Started getting this error while trying to upgrade to NextJS v11 with Webpack v5, only solution I have found was to install @types/node@15.12.2 as a dependency. Still looking for a better solution, but I found this info here if it helps.

https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11640

Comment: `declare global` only works if it is included in the project, and there are a couple of ways to do that. Could you please tell me, in which file do you put `declare global`? Also, is it in the same file as `global.signin = () => {}` ?

Comment: Oh no it’s not in the same file. Had it in another file in my project that was meant for jest setup. It doesn’t have to be in the same file to work because you’re targeting a global namespace which is meant to be available all through your codebase in the same parent folder.

Comment: Maybe try using (global as any).signin = () => {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my own case i didn't quite realize until later that the global namespace i declared was case sensitive.

instead of this. before my question was edited it was `namespace NODEJS`

```
declare global {
  namespace NODEJS {
    interface Global {
      signin(): string[]
    }
  }
}
```

it was supposed to be this

```
declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      signin(): string[]
    }
  }
}
```

pay attention to `NODEJS and NodeJS`. After i made these changes, typescript was cool with it and it work the way i expected it to.

Comment: This doesn't work with the latest versions of `@types/node`.

Comment: And sorry I guess I hijacked your question :p

Answer (score 77):

I was having a similar issue and I found that node's global typings were [changed recently-ish](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/53669); you can now override them by doing:

```
// global.d.ts
declare global {
    function someFunction(): string;
    var someVariable: string;
}
```

Note: this will not work with `let` or `const` you must use `var`.

```
// index.ts
global.someFunction = () => "some value";
global.someVariable = "some value";
```

Comment: I tried but TS says `Statements are not allowed in ambient contexts.`.

Comment: @brillout I edited my answer to make it more clear about what goes in each file

Comment: Not working for me, the compiler still complains with the following message: 'Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature'.

Comment: I needed to add `export {}` to `global.d.ts` to workaround _"Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations."_ . @AnthonyLuzquiños - I wonder if the compiler is aware of your global.d.ts file? I include it in tsconfig.json `{..., "include": ["src/**/*", "global.d.ts"]}`, hth

Comment: I worked, partially. VSCode error is now gone, but I'm still getting the same error when I try to run it. I have created a [project](https://github.com/AnthonyLzq/test-global), in case you want to give it a try. I'm using node 16.13.0, yarn 1.22.17 and my so is: 5.10.79-1-MANJARO.

Comment: @AnthonyLuzquiños. I have the same issue. The VS Code error is gone, but I get ` error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.`

Comment: Hi @Shamoon, I finally solve the issue, it was related to `ts-node`, this is a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610583/ts-node-ignores-d-ts-files-while-tsc-successfully-compiles-the-project) to that, I have also wrote a Medium article about it, [here](https://medium.com/@anthonylzq/how-to-create-global-variables-in-typescript-with-node-js-9ca24f648991) is it.

Comment: Just like to add that I kept tripping up here as i had an the "no-var" ESLint rule however when using declare you must use var and not let or const as I found out.

Comment: @JossBird I edited the answer to clear up any confusion for anyone else that stumbles across this.

Comment: what's the reason that it works with `var`, but not with `let` or `const`?

Comment: This works in node 16

Comment: Getting `TS2669: Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations.` in node18

Answer (score 47):

Below is an example for Node v16

```
// globals.d.ts
declare module globalThis {
    var signin: () => string[];
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the only answer anywhere on the internet that is up to date. Not sure how you knew this answer. My only caveat is it was auto-corrected by my editor to `declare namespace globalThis`

Comment: I second @tettoffensive this is the only one that works in node v16

Comment: where is this `globals.d.ts` supposed to be?
do we need create it or is it already there

Comment: @CircuitPlanet you need create the file with name "globals.d.ts", the typescrit join the config because it is global, so you can create it in any folder of your application

Comment: If you have explicitly provided one or more files in TypeScript's config with the include property (like `"include": [ "src/app.ts" ]`), make sure to also include the *.d.ts file, where you declared your globals (globals.d.ts in this example)

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem with a svelte.kit app. my database module use a global variable to store the dbClient as a promise. VSCode stop complain when the global.d.ts file had this content.

```js
import type { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

declare global {
  namespace globalThis {
    var _mongoClientPromise: Promise<MongoClient>
  }
}
```

Comment: also worked after restarting the vscode once done with these changes

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me with my SvelteKit app.

Answer (score 12):

You should declare a global declared as interface in global.d.ts like this:

```js
export interface global {}
declare global {
  var signin: ()=>string[]
}
```

[The vscode gives correct code hints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge6fV.png)

Answer (score 8):

You have to use the `var` keyword in `declare global`, and remove `namespace NodeJS {`.
Like this:

```js
//globals.d.ts
import type { EventEmitter } from "events";
declare global {
    var myGlobal: EventEmitter;
}
```

```js
/// <reference path="globals.d.ts" />
//index.ts
// reference needs to be at top of file
import { EventEmitter } from "events";
global.myGlobal = new EventEmitter();
global.myGlobal // EventEmitter type: EventEmitter
window.myGlobal // EventEmitter type: EventEmitter
```

Or if you don't have any imports in the `.d.ts` file:

```js
//namedoesntmatter.d.ts
declare var a: string;
```

```js
//index.ts
global.a = "Hello"
global.a //Hello type: string
window.a //Hello type: string
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how I solved with **Node.js V16+**

```
// global.d.ts

export declare global {
   declare module globalThis {
      var MyVar: object;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried everything I found here, but nothing worked.
Even stranger, VSCode showed NO TypeScript errors, but running `tsc` still threw:
`TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.`

After hours, I realised I forgot an `"include": [ "src/app.ts" ]` line in my `tsconfig.json` file.

Note to future self and for those who may have made the same mistake:
*If you have explicitly provided one or more files in TypeScript's config with `include`, and that does not include the *.d.ts file, where you declared your globals, the build will fail with this error, even if VSCode shows no error (because it sees the global declaration, but TypeScript won't).*

Answer (score 3):

I too had the same issue. Fixed it by the below code.

```
declare global {
        function signin(): Promise<string[]>
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

just declare variable by `var` keyword. like this:

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line no-var
var hello = () => { console.log("hello world"); };
// eslint-disable-next-line no-var
var hi: () => number;

globalThis.hello();
globalThis.hi = () => 143;
```

[image]

You can declare variables in `.d.ts` files, too.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me during connect db with next 13.4

```
declare global {
  var mongoose: { conn: any; promise: any };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the global.d.ts file and copy the following code:

```
declare global {
  declare module globalThis {
    var uniqueId: string;
  }
}

export {};
```

And finally, add `"include": ["global.d.ts"]` to the tsconfig.json file

Done!

Answer (score 0):

this fixes it

not `global.signIn` but

```
if (typeof (global as any).signIn === 'function') {
     (global as any).signIn = () => {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**:

I simply find the easiest solution by using `globalThis` like this:

```js
(globalThis as any).myVariableKey = myVariableValue;
```

Because `globalThis` is at top level and you can add what you want, `globalThis` is always any.

Works on CommonJS compilation.

**Documentation**:

[The `globalThis` global property contains the global this value, which is usually akin to the global object.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis)

**Solution**:

```js
(globalThis as any).signin = () => {}; // node global legacy
```

**Way to use your own type**:

Transform `any` as `unknown` as `MyOwnType`

```js
type MyOwnType { // Custom properties };

(globalThis as unknown as MyOwnType).myDefinedPropertyInMyOwnType = value;
```

Answer (score -1):

The error you're encountering when trying to add a function to the global Node.js namespace in a TypeScript environment might be due to TypeScript's built-in type definitions being too restrictive. To address this, you can use declaration merging in a separate file to augment the Node.js types. Here's an example of how you can do this:

```js
// Create a new file, for example, global.d.ts
declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      signin(): string[];
    }
  }
}
```

By placing this code in a file with a `.d.ts` extension (such as `global.d.ts`), you can extend the global namespace without encountering type errors. This allows you to add custom functions to the global Node.js namespace in a TypeScript environment.