# Set up test with Jest, MongoDB and typescript using jest documentation

Tags: typescript, mongodb, jestjs

When I try to set up a simple test file, as per the [jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/mongodb) I get a number of linter errors:

[image: screengrab showing errors]

connection: `Type 'Promise<MongoClient> & void' is missing the following properties from type '{ db: (arg0: any) => any; close: () => any; }': db, closets(2739)`

globalThis.**MONGO_URI**_: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.ts(7017)`

useNewUrlParser: `No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 4, '(url: string, callback: Callback<MongoClient>): void', gave the following error. Argument of type '{ useNewUrlParser: boolean; useUnifiedTopology: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Callback<MongoClient>'....`

I've tried setting up a `global.d.ts` ([as per these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68481686/type-typeof-globalthis-has-no-index-signature)) file with the following declarations in:

```js
export interface globalThis {}
declare module globalThis {
    var __MONGO_URI__: string;
    var __MONGO_DB_NAME__: string;
}

export interface global {}
declare global {
    var __MONGO_URI__: string;
    var __MONGO_DB_NAME__: string;
}
```

I think this solved the `globalThis.__MONGO_URI__` error previously, but I've turned VS Code back on and the error has re-appeared.

package.json dependencies:

```json
 "dependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "node-cron": "^3.0.0",
    "snoostorm": "^1.5.2",
    "snoowrap": "^1.23.0",
    "mongodb": "^4.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.17.12",
    "@shelf/jest-mongodb": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.1",
    "@types/mongodb": "^4.0.7",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.36",
    "@types/node-cron": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/request": "^2.48.8",
    "jest": "^28.1.0",
    "jest-environment-node": "^28.1.0",
    "ts-jest": "^28.0.3",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.2"
  },
```

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks! I've added the package.json dependencies. The file with the errors is a copy and paste from step 3, here: https://jestjs.io/docs/mongodb

Answer (score 1):

For me, it worked using `process.env.MONGO_URL` to replace `globalThis._MONGO_URI_`:

```
connection = await MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
})
```

This way you will be using the test database from the lib @shelf/jest-mongodb.