# Namespace 'NodeJS' has no exported member 'Global'. Replace NodeJS.Global with typeof globalThis

Tags: node.js, typescript

What's the correct way to use `typeof globalThis`? No shortcuts please.

```
interface CustomNodeJsGlobal extends NodeJS.Global {
  foo: {
    bar: string | null
  }
}
```

This obviously will give: `Namespace 'NodeJS' has no exported member 'Global'.ts(2694)`

Comment: Have you given this SO post a read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35074833/16471349

Comment: Deplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/68251777/209727

Answer (score 0):

For node.js 16.x, adding below should work.

```js
declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {}
  }
}
```

For node.js <16, we can install @types/node package
`npm i @types/node@^14` or `npm i @types/node@^15` etc.,