# How to publish types for a Js library that will be included using <script /> tag

Tags: javascript, typescript

Our team publish an `index.js` file that will be included as:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="internal/location/dist/index.js" />
```

in this script, we are adding to the `global` object a new property:

```js
global._superNewProperty = { ... };
```

We want to include the types declaration related to `dist/index.js`;

1. `_superNewProperty` won't exist, generating a fair `ts` error:

```
Property '_superNewProperty' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.ts(2339)
```

I guess we'll need something like:

```
declare global {
  /*
   * let or const variables doesn't show up on globalThis.
   * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68328575/1614677
   */
  /* eslint-disable no-var */
  var _superNewProperty: OurSuperType;
}
```

and... maybe include this using something like

```html
/// <reference types="internal/location/dist/index.d.ts" />
```

2. `dist/index.js` is generated from a `ts` project, how can we expose our type
   `OurSuperType`

```
global._superNewProperty.foo()
global._superNewProperty.goo
global._superNewProperty.hoo.ioo
```